# Redirecting any route to a file using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have been looking for hours on a way to do this, and every solution i found online works fine with one level but not with multiple.

Right now i have this .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php
```

It works fine with the following route `www.example.com/home`
But once i try adding more levels to the route for example `www.example.com/home/test`, nothing works.

JS files are not found, as well as CSS files or images

Comment: When you load the css/js/images, how are you writing the URLs? Does it look like `src="foo/bar.js"` or `src="/foo/bar.js"` (starting with a `/`)? If they don't start with a `/`, try adding that slash in the beginning of the URL's and try again.

Comment: That was one of the problems i had, its working now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try modifying your .htaccess file like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
```

This configuration will check if the requested file or directory does not exist before rewriting the URL to index.php. This should allow you to handle multiple levels of routes while still serving static files like JS, CSS, and images correctly.

Comment: It works! I also had to change the routes a little bit as i was redirecting to ./home instead of /home... Silly me